# Function compiled but no output in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I'm trying to write a stored function that takes an integer N as input and returns the sum of all numbers divisible by 3 or by 5 and less than or equal to N.

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somme_mod(N in INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
as
somme INTEGER:= 0;
i INTEGER:= 0;


BEGIN
    WHILE i <= N LOOP
        IF i MOD 3 = 0 OR i MOD 5 = 0 THEN
            somme := somme + i;
        END IF;
            i := i+1;

    END LOOP;
    RETURN (somme);
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(somme_mod(5));

END;
/
```

I'm getting this:

```
Function SOMME_MOD compiled
```

This version has worked for me

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
FUNCTION somme_mod(N in INTEGER) 
RETURN INTEGER
as
somme INTEGER:= 0;
i INTEGER:= 0;

BEGIN
    WHILE i <= N LOOP
        IF i MOD 3 = 0 OR i MOD 5 = 0 THEN
            somme := somme + i;
        END IF;
        
        i := i+1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN (somme);
END;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(somme_mod(19));
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only compiled the procedure, that's what the CREATE OR REPLACE does - hence that feedback from the database.

Now if you want to actually execute your function, you need to invoke it.

The easiest way to do that is with SQL.

```
select somme_mod(1) from dual;
```

No comment on your PL/SQL but be careful you don't get into a LOOP that NEVER ends...and then never makes it to the RETURN.

Comment: I tried this and it worked
```DECLARE
FUNCTION somme_mod(N in INTEGER) ```

Comment: Did it work just because the function has already been created from the previous scripts? I've read a bit about Function in oracle docs but I'm still confused, is there some way to debug it?

Comment: Right, your create or replace command, if compiled without errors, makes that function available in both SQL and PL/SQL contexts...like our SELECT query there. And yes, there is a pl/sql debugger available, in GUIs like Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the way to do it.  Try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somme_mod(N in INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
as
somme INTEGER:= 0;
i INTEGER:= 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE i <= N LOOP
        IF i MOD 3 = 0 OR i MOD 5 = 0 THEN
            somme := somme + i;
            i := i+1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN (somme);
END;
/

    
select somme_mod(5) from dual;
/
```

or

```
 declare 
   result integer;
 begin
   result := somme_mod(5) ;
   dbms_output.put_line(result);
end;
/
```

Comment: Pretty nice, I tried this ```DECLARE
FUNCTION somme_mod(N in INTEGER) ``` and it worked, I wasn't sure if it's because I already created the function?